# Associativity of function composition?

Tags: group-theory, function-and-relation-composition

I am working on an exercises that should show that [automorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automorphism) under composition satisfy a group definition,
there are basically four things I need to prove:

> 1.closure, 2.associativity, 3.inverse, 4.identity

but I am stuck on number 2, usually for elements in a group ie: 
$$a,b,c \in G$$
if can show associativity by proving:
$$(a \circ b)\circ c = a \circ (b \circ c)$$

but when element of the group are functions....what does it even mean?
I know when "$\circ$" means composition, we have
$$a \circ b \circ c (g) = a(b(c(g)))$$
but what is $$(a \circ b) \circ c (g) = $$
and how do I prove$$(a \circ b)\circ c(g) = a \circ (b \circ c)(g)$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the definition of composition we have:
$$
(g \circ f)(x)=g(f(x)) \quad \forall x \in X
$$
so:
$$
[h \circ (g\circ f)](x)=h((g \circ f)(x))=h(g(f(x)))
$$
and

$$
[(h \circ g)\circ f)](x)=(h\circ g) (f(x))=h(g(f(x)))
$$

Comment: There are a lot of group operations defined to be composition (ie permutation group) but since we kind of always have to process from the right most, does that mean it is always associative?

Answer (score 6):

Things may be clarified if you adjust your parentheses a bit. Suppose $x$ is an element of the domain of $h$. On one hand, we have

$$((f \circ g) \circ h)(x) = (f \circ g)(h(x))= f(g(h(x))),$$

and on the other hand,

$$(f \circ (g \circ h))(x) = f((g \circ h)(x)) = f(g(h(x))).$$

Comment: Does function composition make any stipulations on the codomains/ranges of $f$, $g$, and $h$? For example, according to my book (said a bit awkwardly), the domain of $ f  \circ g$ consists of all $x$ in the domain of $g$ such that $g(x)$ is in the domain of $f$. Can we show that the domain and range of $ (f \circ g) \circ h $ and $ f \circ (g \circ h) $ respectively are the same?